# Sharing cookies between specific subdomains

Tags: spring-boot, servlets, cookies

I'm developing a spring-boot based backend app and an angularjs based frontend app hosted on the same domain with different subdomains.

```
myapp-frontend.mydomain.com //my angularjs app
myapp-backend.mydomain.com //my spring-boot app
otherapp-frontend.mydomain.com //some existing app running on same domain but unrelated
```

I'm trying to set the cookie which contains the jwt token generated in the backend to the browser when login api is called from the angularjs.

Cookie is set into browser with this code when I set the base domain url in spring-boot:

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("Authentication", jwt);
cookie.setPath("/");            
cookie.setDomain("mydomain.com"); //this works
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

This set the cookie for other apps hosted on our company domain, but doesn't share user credentials with my app. Since I want the Authentication cookie header to be visible only to my frontend app, I tried to set the frontend subdomain url in the code. But this doesn't work.

```
...            
cookie.setDomain("myapp-frontend.mydomain.com"); //not setting cookie
...
```

I understand that cookie cannot be set across different domains for security reasons but why is setting the subdomain url not working?

Out of curiosity, I tried putting backend subdomain in the setDomain() and cookie is set under myapp-backend.mydomain.com when I checked in chrome developer tools. Since it's working with base domain url, I believe I have already implemented the CORS correctly.

Am I missing something here? Any input would be greatly appreciated.